# D8 generate double URL for commerce product

Tags: 8, commerce, path-aliases

I need to create double URL alias for commerce product. I tried with code below :

```
function mymodule_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
    if($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'commerce_product'){
        $alias = '/store/'.$entity->getTitle();
        $source = '/product/' . $entity->id();
        $path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save($source, $alias, "en");
    }
}
```

but doesn't work. My alias is overridden by pathauto and I have 2 equal alias.
I need to create /catalog/[commerce_product:title] and /store/[commerce_product:title] URLs.

The first one is set with pathauto pattern and created succesfully. The second one is create with the code above.

After updating the product i have 2 equal URLs:

1. /catalog/product-title
2. /catalog/product-title

why do not I have

1. /catalog/product-title
2. /store/product-title

how can I save double different alias?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you setting `$alias`? Please provide your complete code example.

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: Your example is still bogus. Setting all products to the same alias obviously won't work. Please share your actual code.

Comment: i updated the code with the right alias text.

Answer (score 1):

In your hook_entity_update() do like below

```
    function mymodule_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
      if($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'commerce_product'){
        $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
        $aliasStorage = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage');
        $source = '/product/' . $entity->id();
        if ($aliasStorage->aliasExists($source, $langcode)) {
          // alias already exist. So save your second alias here.
          $aliasStorage->save('/product/' . $entity->id(), YOURNEWALIAS, $language);

        }
        else {
           $aliasStorage->save('/product/' . $entity->id(), YOURNEWALIAS_1, $language);
           $aliasStorage->save('/product/' . $entity->id(), YOURNEWALIAS_2, $language);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is almost the same as mine. i think that YOURNEWALIAS is overriden by pathauto patterns. I have updated the question for more informations. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function mymodule_node_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {
  multiple_alias_callback($node);
}

function multiple_alias_callback(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {
// Set of conditions as per your requirement
  $new_alias_val = '/your/custom/new/alias';
  $node->path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save('/node/' . $node->id(), $new_alias_val);
}
```

This is example for saving multiple alias for node, you can use that for saving multiple alias for entity. Please update your code like this **$node->path** for saving.

Answer (score 0):

To store double URL alias you have to disable pathauto patterns created in 
admin/config/search/path/patterns.
Generate desired pattern for products or nodes. In this example pattern_id_1, pattern_id_2.
Disable them.

After that you have to use this code:

```
function MYMODULE_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
    // Convert to lowercase, trim spaces, replace spaces with underscore and then truncate to 60 chars.
    if($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'commerce_product'){
        //aggiungo URL sezione store
        $aliasStorage = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage');
        $langcode = $entity->language()->getId();
        $source = '/product/' . $entity->id();

        $alias = MYMODULE_get_product_alias($entity, 'pattern_id_1');

        if($alias){
            if ( !$aliasStorage->aliasExists($alias, $langcode, $source) ) {
                $path = $aliasStorage->save($source, $alias, $langcode);

            }
        }

        $alias = MYMODULE_get_product_alias($entity, 'pattern_id_2');

        if($alias){
            if ( !$aliasStorage->aliasExists($alias, $langcode, $source) ) {
                $path = $aliasStorage->save($source, $alias, $langcode);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

and this to create alias with second pattern.

```
function MYMODULE_get_product_alias($entity, $pattern_key){

    $pattern = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('pathauto_pattern')->load($pattern_key);

    $tokenEntityMapper = \Drupal::service('token.entity_mapper');
    $aliasCleaner = \Drupal::service('pathauto.alias_cleaner');
    $storage = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage');
    $token = \Drupal::service('token');

    $langcode = $entity->language()->getId();

    // Build token data.
    $data = [
        $tokenEntityMapper->getTokenTypeForEntityType($entity->getEntityTypeId()) => $entity,
    ];

    // Replace any tokens in the pattern.
    // Uses callback option to clean replacements. No sanitization.
    // Pass empty BubbleableMetadata object to explicitly ignore cacheablity,
    // as the result is never rendered.
    $alias = $token->replace($pattern->getPattern(), $data, array(
        'clear' => TRUE,
        'callback' => array($aliasCleaner, 'cleanTokenValues'),
        'langcode' => $langcode,
        'pathauto' => TRUE,
    ), new BubbleableMetadata());

    // Check if the token replacement has not actually replaced any values. If
    // that is the case, then stop because we should not generate an alias.
    // @see token_scan()
    $pattern_tokens_removed = preg_replace('/\[[^\s\]:]*:[^\s\]]*\]/', '', $pattern->getPattern());

    if ($alias === $pattern_tokens_removed) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return $aliasCleaner->cleanAlias($alias);
}
```

Without disable patterns, the URL created programmatically was overriden by pathauto.